# How to get rid of the resize attribute error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

I'd like to know if I did something wrong in my code or if I have to update something cause every single time I try to resize an image I have this:  Attribute Error 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize'.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image1 = Image.open("enseigne.JPEG")
image1= ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
imageresize = image1.thumbnail((500,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
imageresize = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageresize)
limage = tk.Label(app, image=imageresize)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means what it says, `PhotoImage` object does not have `resize` attribute, then what has? It is the `Image` object that has `resize`. You can remove your first `PhotoImage`(because it uses `resize`), as its no use:

```
image1 = Image.open("enseigne.JPEG")
imageresize = image1.thumbnail((500,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
imageresize = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageresize)
limage = tk.Label(app, image=imageresize)
```

If you want shorter code:

```
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("enseigne.JPEG").thumbnail((500,500), Image.ANTIALIAS))

limage = tk.Label(app, image=image1)
```

---

Obvious question: You are not calling `resize` but why are you getting such error? It is because `thumbnail` uses `resize` implicitly(based on conditions).

Comment: Thanks a lot I finally understand my error