# TKinter: resize thumbnail in a canvas after a For Loop

Tags: python, tkinter

In a folder I have 256 images. I load them as thumbnails with a for loop.
I wish to click on one of them and then have it enlarged in a canvas.

The code I am using is:

```
A = Canvas(my_frame1, bg="blue", height=650, width=650)
A.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NW)
B = Canvas(my_frame1, bg="green", height=550, width=550)
B.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NW)
C = Canvas(my_frame1, bg="white", height=256, width=256)
C.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=NW)

def several():
    val_x=x.get()
    image_id = C.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=img_list[val_x-1])

img_list=[]
path = "./gfx"
n_row = 0
n_col = 0
index = 0
x = IntVar()
for f in os.listdir(path):
    img_list.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(path,f))))
    n_col +=1
    index +=1
    if n_col > 9:
        n_row +=1
        n_col = 1
    tile = Radiobutton(A, image=img_list[index-1], indicatoron=0, bd=2, variable = x, value = index, selectcolor="red", command=several)
    tile.grid(row=n_row, column = n_col)

root.mainloop()
```

This code works but doesn't resize the image.

I tried:

```
def several():
    val_x=x.get()
    img_a=img_list[val_x-1]
    img_b = img_a.resize((256, 256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img_c = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_b)
    image_id = C.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=img_c)
    C.itemconfig(image_id)
```

and I get this error:

```
****Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\python_edit_binary\test.py", line 52, in several
    img_b = img_a.resize((256, 256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize'****
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

After some research, I have written this code that works but strangely:

```
def several():
    val_x=x.get()
    img_canvas = []
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        img_canvas.append(Image.open(os.path.join(path,f)))
    img_a=(img_canvas[val_x-1])
    img_b = img_a.resize((256, 256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img_c = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_b)
    image_id = C.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=img_c)
    C.itemconfig(image_id)
    print(img_id)
```

As I said it works perfectly: the image is resized and showed in the canvas !!! But I get also an error because I mispelled **print(image_id)** into **print(img_id)**.

```
NameError: name 'img_id' is not defined
```

If I remove the command print(img_id) or correct it the image is no more showed.

I have also tried other solutions and, as long as I produced an error, the code works.

It is so strange, isn't it?

Comment: I tried to edit my post in order to greet everybody but my modifications are not saved... Sorry.

Comment: As the error said, `PhotoImage()` does not have `resize()` function.  You need to call it on the instance of `Image.open(...)` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of the resize attribute error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67425476/how-to-get-rid-of-the-resize-attribute-error)

Comment: Hi. I've read that thread but I am unable to use the function Image.open() with my list of images.